# Gem install pg works but bundle install fails

Tags: ruby, macos, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

There is very lot of topics about this but I already try almost all of them with no success.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.9.4 Mavericks, I have the Postgres.app, and it seams to work fine, `sudo gem install pg` works too :

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-0.17.1
invalid options: -f fivefish
(invalid options are ignored)
Parsing documentation for pg-0.17.1
Done installing documentation for pg after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

but when I try to `bundle install` I have the same error than every one else.

- I already try `bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config`
  then `bundle install`
- I have the Xcode Command Line Tools.
- `which psql`return `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/psql`
- `which postgres`return `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/postgres`

Here is the error for `bundle install`:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config
    checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/07/my1cl5xj7g9cknnp3y2zg_rh0000gn/T/bundler20140723-29399-1o0uzqn/pg-0.17.1/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/07/my1cl5xj7g9cknnp3y2zg_rh0000gn/T/bundler20140723-29399-1o0uzqn/pg-0.17.1/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/pg-0.17.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days I finally found the problem source (ironically when I decide to give up, and move on).

When I do a 
`which bundle` and `which gem`
They were not from the same ruby installation.
bundle was from rbenv and gem from the preinstalled ruby on mac osx.

Comment: Can you be more detailed? I have the same problem - what are the steps you took to resolve this?

Comment: If my memories are good, I re-installed all of them with rbenv. gem bundle as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353382/setting-up-env-osx-rbenv-and-bundle-battle

Answer (score 0):

might have the permission issue. can use:

sudo bundle install --without nothing --path vendor/cache